# Is the speed of a pendulum symmetric?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry

Suppose a pendulum moves with simple harmonic motion and there is some point P which it passes: will the time to go from O to P be equal to the time taken to go from P to O when it is coming back from an extreme?

Mathematical additions to explanations will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a conceptual homework-like exercise that a teacher would use.  Especially suspicious is the request for a mathematical addition. Why not show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Why do you think it might be asymmetric? Are you assuming that there is no air resistance or other energy losses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be equal. It is basically result of symmetry.

SHM means $y=A\sin(\omega t)$ where $y$ is displacement from mean position. So time taken from $O$ to $P$ is,
$$t= \frac{\arcsin (y_1/A)-\arcsin (y_2/A)}{\omega},$$
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the displacements at $O$ and $P$. Clearly, it depends only displacement and nothing else.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please do not post formulae as mere text, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead. Also, consider using proper spacing, i.e. putting a space behind every punctuation mark.